# Is there a way to erase the last line of output?

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, ansi-escape

A very simple program that prints 3 lines of output:

```
console.log('a');
console.log('b');
console.log('c');
```

Is there a way from program to delete the last line after it has been printed?, i.e.

```
console.log('a');
console.log('b');
console.log('c');
clearLastLine();
console.log('C');
```

which would produce:

```
a
b
C
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The simple solution is to not print a newline character (i.e., do not use `console.log`).

- Use `process.stdout.write` to print a line without the EOL character.
- Use carriage return (`\r`) character to return to the begin of the line.
- Use [`\e[K`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_sequences) to clear all characters from the cursor position to the end of the line.

Example:

```js
process.stdout.write("000");
process.stdout.write("\n111");
process.stdout.write("\n222");
```

To this line, the output will be:

```js
000
111
222
```

However, if you execute:

```js
process.stdout.write("000");
process.stdout.write("\n111");
process.stdout.write("\n222");
process.stdout.write("\r\x1b[K")
process.stdout.write("333");
```

The output is:

```js
000
111
222\r\x1b[K
333
```

However, the terminal will display:

```js
000
111
333
```

Comment: What's the difference between `\e[K` and `\x1b[K`?

Comment: `\e` is an escape character in bash but does very little in node. `\x1b` is the specific character with hex value `1b`. Use the latter in node

Answer (score 41):

Way 1:

```
const clearLastLine = () => {
  process.stdout.moveCursor(0, -1) // up one line
  process.stdout.clearLine(1) // from cursor to end
}
```

Way 2:

```
const readline = require('readline')

const clearLastLine = () => {
  readline.moveCursor(process.stdout, 0, -1) // up one line
  readline.clearLine(process.stdout, 1) // from cursor to end
}
```

Way 3:

```
const ESC = '\x1b' // ASCII escape character
const CSI = ESC + '[' // control sequence introducer

const clearLastLine = () => {
  process.stdout.write(CSI + 'A') // moves cursor up one line
  process.stdout.write(CSI + 'K') // clears from cursor to line end
}
```

Way 1 uses the methods provided by the built-in [`tty`](https://nodejs.org/api/tty.html) module.

Way 2 uses the built-in [`readline`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) module.

Way 3 uses [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

I learned about [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) by viewing the source code of [log-update](https://github.com/sindresorhus/log-update), which I found out about from [dthree](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1730638/dthree)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32938331/242933). After doing some more research, I learned about the built-in [`readline`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) and [`tty`](https://nodejs.org/api/tty.html) modules.

By reading the source code of [Node.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node), I learned that the methods used in way 1 are essentially wrappers around the methods used in way 2 and that the methods used in way 2 are essentially wrappers around the methods used in way 3. So every way ends up doing basically the same thing under the hood. I've ordered the ways from higher-level to lower-level.

I suggest using way 1 over way 2 and way 2 over way 3 mainly because I think that way 1 is less code and more clear (and therefore more readable) than way 2 and that way 2 is less code and more clear (and therefore more readable) than way 3 and that performance improvements (if any) achieved by using a lower-level way are likely negligible. However, I think way 3 avoids loading the built-in [`readline`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) module.

This solution (every way) assumes your cursor is at the start of an empty line right before your program calls `clearLastLine()`. As [Gajus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/368691/gajus) states in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32938658/242933), the solution is simpler if instead your cursor is at the end of the last line. So could you use [`process.stdout.write()`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_write_data_encoding_callback) (instead of [`console.log()`](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_log_data_args)) to print the last line without a trailing newline?

Or the solution is even simpler if you don't need to print the last line in the first place. Is all this tinkering with stdout a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)? Could you rearchitect your code so that the last line doesn't get printed at all?

In my case I'm testing a helper function I wrote that calls [`console.error()`](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_log_data_args), and I don't want the logged error message to show up in my test output. So instead of having my helper function call [`console.error()`](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_log_data_args), I could make it throw an error (or just return an error code and/or message or a boolean). And then my main program that calls my helper function could call [`console.error()`](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_log_data_args) if my helper function throws an error (or returns an an error code and/or message or `false`). Or I could pass a boolean [flag argument](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/FlagArgument.html) to my helper function that tells it whether or not to log an error. Or I could redirect stderr, or [mock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) the global [`console`](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html) or [stub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_stub) [`console.error()`](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_log_data_args), etc.

If you wanted to clear the last three lines written to `system.stdout`, you could do:

```
const clearLastLines = (count) => {
  process.stdout.moveCursor(0, -count)
  process.stdout.clearScreenDown()
}

clearLastLines(3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! What a hidden gem.

Answer (score 15):

The following works for me:

```
process.stdout.clearLine();
process.stdout.cursorTo(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`logUpdate`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/log-update) NPM module, or the [`vorpal`](https://github.com/dthree/vorpal) NPM module. These both do that.

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple workaround:

```
process.stdout.write(`\x1Bc\rData left: ${currentPercentage}%`)
```

That would print something like:
"Data left: 100%"... and by using that, you would clear the screen after each iteration.

'\x1Bc' clear the line, and '\r' returns to column 0.

Answer (score 1):

The only module that worked for me without erasing everything before the progress bar was [`single-line-log`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/single-line-log)

Install it with:

```
npm i single-line-log
```

Import it with:

```
var log = require('single-line-log').stdout;
```

Then instead of logging the progress bar with `console.log()`, just use `log()`:

```
// OLD:
while (task_is_running) {
    console.log(Progress.update())
}

// NEW:
while (task_is_running) {
    log(Progress.update())
}
```

Combined with [`clui`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clui) for the progress bar, this works great.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me, to clear last terminal line (or "erase the last line of output") with node.js. I use this after progress bars complete.

```
process.stdout.moveCursor(0, -1)
process.stdout.clearScreenDown()
```